# jquery scrollto top height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had multiple dynamic content sections. Each sections have heading tag.

```
First section h2 class name is "bounceInRight"
First section h2 class name is "bounceInLeft"
third section h2 class name is "bounceInRight"
Fourth section h2 class name is "bounceInLeft" and goes on.
```

If I reach this class I need to add some class to another div name "blink".

For this I used the following code:

```
var eyemoveright = $(".bounceInRight h2").offset().top;
var eyemoveleft = $(".bounceInLeft h2").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() > eyemoveright) { 

        $('.blink').addClass( "move-right");
        $('.blink1').addClass( "move-right");
    }   

    if($(window).scrollTop() > eyemoveleft) { 

        $('.blink').addClass( "move-left");
        $('.blink1').addClass( "move-left");
    }                               
});
```

Please see the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zvkjfk6r/

For the first two sections are working fine. The classes are added correctly. If the third content block reached, the add classes not working. Because I used two if condition. How to call the first If condition again, if the third block content reached??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u should use loop through each section and set a flag for already reached section.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".bounceInRight h2").each(function(){
        var eyemoveright = $(this).offset().top;
        if($(window).scrollTop() > eyemoveright && !$(this).hasClass('reached')) {
            console.log('right');
            $(this).addClass('reached');
            $('.blink').addClass( "move-right");
            $('.blink1').addClass( "move-right");
            $('.blink').removeClass( "move-left");
            $('.blink1').removeClass( "move-left");
        }
    })

    $(".bounceInLeft h2").each(function(){
        var eyemoveleft = $(this).offset().top;
        if($(window).scrollTop() > eyemoveleft && !$(this).hasClass('reached')) { 
            console.log('left');
            $(this).addClass('reached');
            $('.blink').addClass( "move-left");
            $('.blink1').addClass( "move-left");           
            $('.blink').removeClass( "move-right");
            $('.blink1').removeClass( "move-right");
        }   
    })  


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ashish1bhagat/zvkjfk6r/7/

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code. I am not reach my block content, but the classes are added.

Comment: Oh! remove `$(window).height()` from both condition,   try using `var eyemoveleft = $(this).offset().top;`  and  `var eyemoveright = $(this).offset().top` only

Comment: Thank you. I used your code and slightly modified. It is working good.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any problem if the second if condition is written inside the first one
Because it will never go in the second if

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > eyemoveleft) { 

           console.log("seconfif");
            $('.blink').addClass( "move-left");
            $('.blink1').addClass( "move-left");
        }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zvkjfk6r/1/)**

**Second Method**

```
 if(eyemoveright< $(window).scrollTop() && $(window).scrollTop() > eyemoveleft) { 

           console.log("seconfif");
            $('.blink').addClass( "move-left");
            $('.blink1').addClass( "move-left");
        }
```

**[2nd Method JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zvkjfk6r/3/)**

[After removing class](http://jsfiddle.net/zvkjfk6r/8/)

Comment: I tried your code. If I reach the 3rd i need to add the class like 1st block section.

Comment: Actually this animation is man eye following. Man follows the title section. so the eye ball move to see the title. The title is displayed left or right side.

Comment: For that it is necessary to removeClass whenever not needed.

Comment: i tried your 2nd method. I reached the 3rd block "move-left" class should be removed. but it is not removed. The fourth, fifth... also this class display like this "blink1 move-right move-left".

Answer (score 0):

You should add this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() < eyemoveright) { 
  $('.blink').removeClass( "move-right");
  $('.blink1').removeClass( "move-right");
}
```

like below.

```js
  var eyemoveright = $(".bounceInRight h2").offset().top;
  var eyemoveleft = $(".bounceInLeft h2").offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    
    if($(window).scrollTop() > eyemoveright) { 
      

      $('.blink').addClass( "move-right");
      $('.blink1').addClass( "move-right");
    } 

    if($(window).scrollTop() < eyemoveright) { 
      

      $('.blink').removeClass( "move-right");
      $('.blink1').removeClass( "move-right");
    } 

    if($(window).scrollTop() > eyemoveleft) { 
     
     
      $('.blink').addClass( "move-left");
      $('.blink1').addClass( "move-left");
    }               
  });
```

```css
.blink, .blink1{ background-color:#fff; width:3px; height:3px; position:absolute; animation: blink 2s steps(5, start) infinite; -webkit-animation: blink 2s steps(5, start) infinite; left:90px; top:64px;  }
  .blink1{ left:124px; top:65px;  }
  @keyframes blink {
    to {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes blink {
    to {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
  
  .blink.move-right{left:50px;}
  .blink1.move-right{left:56px;}


  .blink.move-left{left:10px;}
  .blink1.move-left{left:15px;}
  .animation-image{ width:200px; height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-image text-center" style="position:fixed;  background-color:red;"><span class="blink1 hidden-mob"></span><span class="blink hidden-mob"></span></div>
<br><br><br><br>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

</p>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-sm-5  bounceInRight">
  <h2>Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pa</h2>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <div class="col-sm-5  bounceInLeft">
    <h2>Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pa</h2>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <div class="col-sm-5  bounceInRight">
      <h2>Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pa</h2>
    </div>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <div class="col-sm-5  bounceInRight">
      <h2>Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pa</h2>
    </div>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <div class="col-sm-5  bounceInRight">
      <h2>Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum pa</h2>
    </div>
```